# Exponential algebra problem: Equating powers

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

Given Data:

5 <sup>a</sup>  = 26
 
125 <sup>b</sup>  = 676

What is the relation between a and b?

I simplified 125 <sup>b</sup> = 5 <sup>4</sup> + 5 <sup>a</sup>

but how to equate a and b in above relation?

Note:
Answer should be in the format x*a = y*b +/- z where x,y & z are real numbers greater than or equal to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$5^3=125$$
so
$$5^{3b}=676$$
Also,
$$26^2=676$$
So
$$(5^a)^2=676=5^{2a}$$
Using this, we get
$$5^{2a}=5^{3b}$$
From here, it's algebra.

Comment: Key here is to know 26<sup>2</sup> = 676, but how do I solve this incase, I do not know that 26<sup>2</sup> = 676

Comment: You could try to use logs to see if there's a pattern (i.e. $\log_{26}676=?$).